# Executor in Mirco-ROS and ROS2

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I have recently read into micro-ROS, ROS2 and learnt about its executor. I have a few questions about the current state of the executor in Micro-ROS and ROS2.

1. Does the [callback-group-level executor](https://micro.ros.org/docs/concepts/client_library/execution_management/#callback-group-level-executor) concept apply in micro-ROS? I see that it has been merged into ROS2 rclcpp, but since micro-ROS doesn't support rclcpp, I'm a bit confused.
2. In the [rclc repo](https://github.com/ros2/rclc), it mentioned that "The software is not ready for production use. It has neither been developed nor tested for a specific use case.". Does that mean micro-ROS is also not ready for production use? Does rclc executor included in the releases of ROS2 Humble and Rolling version?
3. In the [concept page](https://micro.ros.org/docs/concepts/client_library/execution_management/#future-work), it mentioned that "Multi-threaded executor with assignment of scheduling policies of underlying operating system." is a future work with an open PR. Later, there was an [announcement](https://micro.ros.org/blog/2021/07/07/multithreading/) about micro-ROS multithreading support. Is it the same as the multi-threaded executor mentioned in the concept page? If not, what are the differences?
4. Can you use C++ user code on top of the rclc? (for both case of using rclc with ROS2 and rclc with Micro-ROS)

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/412704/executor-in-mirco-ros-and-ros2/) by [vutran1410](https://answers.ros.org/users/140040/vutran1410/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @vultran1410

> .1.   Does the callback-group-level executor concept apply in micro-ROS? I see that it has been merged into ROS2 rclcpp,
> but since micro-ROS doesn't support rclcpp, I'm a bit confused.
> No, the callback group-level Executor is only available in rclcpp, aka ROS 2. However, you don't need callback groups in micro-ROS (rclc): In ROS 2, you can only add nodes to an Executor, if you add multiple communication objects, like subscriptions, to a node, all subscriptions are added to the Executor. If you want to use different priorities for executing the callbacks WITHIN a node, this was not possible in ROS 2. Therefore, you can create a callback group and assign subscriptions to it. And then add a callback group to an Executor.

In micro-ROS, there is no hierarchical structure of subscriptions, nodes, executor ... like in ROS 2:

```
subscription0 --> node0 --> executor0

subscription1 --> node1  
subscription2 --> node1  
subscription1 --> callback_group1
subscription2 --> callback_group2
callback_group1 --> executor1
callback_group2 --> executor2
```

but it is flat, that is you can direclty add subscriptions to an Executor:

```
subscription0 --> node0
subscription1 --> node1
subscription2 --> node1
subscription0 --> executor0
subscription1 --> executor1
subscription2 --> executor2
```

That is, you add directly subscriptions to executor. You don't need a callback-group in micro-ROS.
Of course, I agree it would make sense to have the same API in ROS 2 as well as in micro-ROS. I could think of a thin-API that would mimick a callback group, just to have the same API as in ROS 2, but essentially it would also just add all subscriptions of the callback group to the Executor.
(I will update the documentation in micro-ROS accordingly).

What would you prefer? Is it okay for you, if you could add subscriptions to an Executor directly?

> .2. In the rclc repo, it mentioned that "The software is not ready for production use. It has neither been developed nor tested for a specific use case.". Does that mean micro-ROS is also not ready for production use? Does rclc executor included in the releases of ROS2 Humble and Rolling version?

This is rather a liability exclusion. It has been used in several commercial products. All unit tests are running successfully for Foxy, Humble, Rolling. We achieve [ROS 2 Quality Level 2](https://github.com/ros2/rclc/blob/master/rclc/QUALITY_DECLARATION.md) for the rclc library.

> Does rclc executor included in the releases of ROS2 Humble and Rolling version?

the rclc-package is not part of the default ROS 2 distribution, but you can install the binary package like any other ROS 2 package with e.g. `sudo apt-get install ros-humble-rclc`. [micro-ROS supports ROS 2 distrubutions: Foxy, Humble, Rolling](https://github.com/ros2/rclc/#bloom-release-status-of-code-repository-ros2rclc)

> .3. In the concept page, it mentioned that "Multi-threaded executor with assignment of scheduling policies of underlying operating system." is a future work with an open PR. Later, there was an announcement about micro-ROS multithreading support. Is it the same as the multi-threaded executor mentioned in the concept page? If not, what are the differences?

No. These are different things.  The multi-threaded Executor will support processing subscriptions in different threads (with different real-time priorities) via rclc-API.

I am currently working on a branch to re-structure the rclc-Executor, so that it can support single-threaded, multi-threaded (POSIX), and non-POSIX (AUTOSAR) operating systems. working branch: [restructured-rclc-executor](https://github.com/micro-ROS/rclc/tree/feature/restructured-exectutor).

"micro-ROS multithreading support" revers to the fact, that the micro-ROS client (with its XRCE-DDS middleware) is thread-safe. That means, you can create multiple threads, in these threads create multiple micro-ROS clients (with e.g. subscription, executors, etc.). The multi-threading support is on the level of the middleware. On API level, you have only a "single-threaded" Executor. But you could create multiple "single-threaded Executors" in different threads.

> Can you use C++ user code on top of the rclc? (for both case of using rclc with ROS2 and rclc with Micro-ROS)

Yes, you can always call a C function from C++ code. There are limitations regarding full C++ semantics for e.g. callback functions. But you can use a static C++ member class method as a callback function. See [this example](https://github.com/ros2/rclc/tree/master/rclc_examples#subscription-callback-with-c-class-method). Additionally, you can [add a context pointer to a subscription](https://github.com/ros2/rclc/blob/3b4ff9e46ad63ca08a1131760a86b0f42c2bba63/rclc/include/rclc/executor.h#L276). Then its callback function is called with the new message and has this pointer as a parameter.

See also the open [issue#126](https://github.com/ros2/rclc/issues/126) about a discussion to provide a C++ API for rclc.

You can use rclc from ROS 2 (using any DDS middleware) or as a micro-ROS client on a micro-controller (using XRCE-DDS middleware). the rclc-package depends only on the rcl layer and does not require anything specific from the underlying middleware.

---

Originally posted by [JanStaschulat](https://answers.ros.org/users/100928/janstaschulat/) with karma: 81 on 2023-02-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vutran1410](https://answers.ros.org/users/140040/vutran1410/) on 2023-02-22**:
Thank you for your detailed answers!

"In micro-ROS, there is no hierarchical structure of subscriptions, nodes, executor ... like in ROS 2" --> Does that mean if I'm using rclc for ROS2, it will also have no hierarchical structure and I can add subscriptions directly to the executors?

**Comment by [JanStaschulat](https://answers.ros.org/users/100928/janstaschulat/) on 2023-02-22**:
Yes. You can use rclc-package as an API for a normal ROS 2 application (using C programming language or some restricted C++ language). You can add subscriptions to the rclc-Executor directly (if you are using the rclc-package).